# $.ajax file upload timeouts with large files

Tags: php, nginx

I have a PHP application running on NGINX web server. We discovered a problem where large files cause an $.ajax timeout when uploaded. I was told the $.ajax timeout values will not help as this is a browser vs. server issue. Is there practice that's common to resolve this issue?

Comment: What web browser? How long does it take the timeout to trigger? What are your server settings? What value have you supplied for the AJAX timeout parameter? **Who** told you that AJAX timeout values will not help; how do **I** know this person is knowledgeable?

Comment: Safari. The NGNIX server settings do not mention a timeout.  I will definitely try to put a value in the $.ajax timeout to try. Is any known PHP.ini or NGNIX configuration element I should be looking into as well?

Comment: I do not know the timeout. It happened to users in the field and they described it as under a minute. And no. I am not sure the person who mentioned the $.ajax timeout is an expert in his field.

Comment: PHP has a `max_execution_time` directive. There is also a `max_input_time` directive but I am 99% sure you are not hitting it. What was the filesize? There is a `upload_max_filesize` directive. If the user was in the field then it is possible they lost their network connection. I am not familiar with NGINX settings. If I were you then I would download a CentOS DVD ISO and try uploading it into your system and see if the timeout is reproduce-able. Test multiple browsers. Use Chrome on the desktop because it has incredible debugging tools; hit F12.

Comment: Last, but certainly not least, check your PHP and NGINX logs for errors.

Comment: What's your PHP `memory_limit` set to? Was this hit? If so, then you should see it in your PHP logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems I was fed wrong information. This was NO timeout. It was an HTTP Error 413 Request entity too large.

Adding this to the NGINX configuration file:

```
client_max_body_size 100M;
```

and these to /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini:

```
post_max_size = 12M
upload_max_filesize = 10M
```

resolved the issue.